# PHP MYSQL Register page Validation

Tags: php, mysql

Another question regarding php and mysql... I'm wandering if it makes sense..

Basically above that code below.. is the form.. I want it to go through the validation with error counts.(code stated below) If counted error is 0, run that "INSERT INTO" code.. if counted error is 1 or more, show error and data not sent out.

But one thing though.. the code stated below doesn't actually "work" and doesnt give any errors :(

All comments really appreciated!
Thanks very much

```
  <?php
    global $pdo;
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=clubresults', 'root', '12345678');
    #Set Error Mode to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION.
    $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  

    ?>

<<<<<<<FORM GOES HERE>>>>>>>>

<?php

function validatePattern(&$errors, $field_list, $field_name, $pattern)
{
    if (!isset($field_list[$field_name]) || $field_list[$firld_name] == '')
        $errors[$field_name] = 'Required';
    else if (!preg_match($pattern, $field_list[$field_name]))
        $errors[$field_name] = 'Invalid';
}
    $errors = array();
    validatePattern($errors, $_GET, ':firstname', '/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z -]+$/');
    validatePattern($errors, $_GET, ':surname', '/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z -]+$/');
    validatePattern($errors, $_GET, ':Player1', '/^[0-9a-zA-Z_]$/');
    validatePattern($errors, $_GET, ':Player2', '/^[0-9a-zA-Z_]$/');    
    validatePattern($errors, $_GET, ':Player3', '/^[0-9a-zA-Z_]$/');
    validatePattern($errors, $_GET, ':Player4', '/^[0-9a-zA-Z_]$/');    
    validatePattern($errors, $_GET, ':Player5', '/^[0-9a-zA-Z_]$/');    


    if (count($errors) >0){
echo "<font face='Verdana' size='2' color=red>$msg</font><br><input type='button' value='Retry' onClick='history.go(-1)'>";
}else{
if(("$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO members (firstname, surname, DD, MM, YYYY, email, Player1, Player2, Player3, Player4, Player5)
VALUES (:firstname, :surname, :DD, :MM, :YYYY, :email, :Player1, :Player2, :Player3, :Player4, :Player5)');
$stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $_GET['firstname']);
$stmt->bindParam(':surname', $_GET['surname']);
$stmt->bindParam(':DD', $_GET['DD']);
$stmt->bindParam(':MM', $_GET['MM']);
$stmt->bindParam(':YYYY', $_GET['YYYY']);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $_GET['email']);
$stmt->bindParam(':Player1', $_GET['Player1']);
$stmt->bindParam(':Player2', $_GET['Player2']);
$stmt->bindParam(':Player3', $_GET['Player3']);
$stmt->bindParam(':Player4', $_GET['Player4']);
$stmt->bindParam(':Player5', $_GET['Player5']);
$stmt->execute();")){
echo "<font face='Verdana' size='2' color=green>Welcome, You have successfully signed up</font>";}
else{ echo "Database Problem, please contact Site admin";
}
?>
```

Comment: you should change `$field_list` to `&$field_list` as $_GET can get (hehe) very large.

Comment: done! thanks for your suggestion. but one thing tho.. the code above doesnt actually work and I cant find the reason why it doesnt work :(

Comment: umm form validating from php isn't the best way, have you tried using jquery validator?

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I'm not allowed to use any third party codes like jQuery jomla etc..

Comment: `if(("$stmt = ` - is that `"` a typo? It really shouldn't be there, it's going to cause a parse error.

Comment: Ah I didn't notice it. I'll remove it :P thanks for your suggestion

Comment: One question.. the if(($stmt=    is that a valid if statement? Should it work?

Answer (score 0):

check with this for submit

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
//get data and validation code comes here 
}else{
//your form comes here
}
```

i hope this will work

Comment: ill give it a try when i get back from uni! thanks for your suggestion!